# Verify Shopify webhook with many possible secrets

Tags: javascript, security, shopify, webhooks

I've created a dashboard that aggregates order processing for multiple Shopify stores. It's a private app so I save each Shopify store's API credentials and webhook secret in my database. I've encrypted all this sensitive stuff with a key that's stored as an environment variable. For any given event, I direct all Shopify stores to the same callback URL. Hence for each url I'll have to verify the request body against all possible webhook secrets, which are stored in the database. I have 2 questions:

1. Is this an acceptable approach for securing the stores' API credentials and webhook secrets?
2. How do I synchronously verify the request body if my secrets are stored in the database? My verify function is below.

```js
  verify: (buffer, hmacHeader) => {
    Brand.find().exec((err, brands) => {
      if (!err && brands) {
        const allWebhookSecrets = brands.map(brand => {
          console.log(`encrypted webhook secret is: ${brand.shopify_webhook_secret_encrypted}`)
          return encryption.decrypt(brand.shopify_webhook_secret_encrypted);
        });
        const webhookIsValid = allWebhookSecrets.some(secret => {
          var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
            .update(buffer)
            .digest('base64');
          return hmac == hmacHeader;
        });
        console.log(`webhookIsValid: ${webhookIsValid}`);
        return webhookIsValid;
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the only thing you should really be storing in your database is the stores access token for your app and any other verification data for the store login. Webhook signatures and generated differently every time a request is sent to your app using your apps shared secret and the data the webhook is about to send to you.

Webhooks are verified using your apps shared secret and the post request data to the HMAC signature sent in the header: `X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256`.

This is my simplified nodejs implementation of a webhook verification middleware

```
function verify_webhook(postData, hmac) {
    if (!hmac || !postData || typeof postData !== 'object') {
      return false;
    }

    const calculatedSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', process.env.SHOPIFY_SHARED_SECRET)
    .update(postData)
    .digest('hex');
    return calculatedSignature === hmac;
  }
```

where postData and hmac are `JSON.stringify(req.body)` and `req.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256')`

There's generally no point storing this information in a database and just calculating it and verifying it on a fly using middleware. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not actually storing the signature in the database, just the different secrets of the different stores connecting to the app. I can't store these secrets as environment variables since stores are removed and added dynamically. So I'm wondering if storing secrets as plain text in a database is a good idea.

Comment: As for the verification code, since the secrets are stored in the database, they have to be retrieved asynchronously. To abort the processing of the buffer (rejecting the webhook request), an error could be thrown but can I still throw an error after an asynchronous database call?